# why do we have to open file multiple times in a function in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a = open("prime_numbers.txt", 'r+')
b = open('happy_numbers.txt','r+')
c = a.read().split()
d = b.read().split()
def overlap(list1,list2):
    e= open('final_number_list.txt','r+')
    for i in list1:
       for j in list2:
           if i == j:
             e.write(i+'\n')
           else:continue
    e = open('final_number_list.txt', 'r+')
    print(e.read().split())
overlap(c,d)
```

Why i have to use open command for the 2nd time? If i will not use it for the 2nd time the command overlap(c,d) will print a empty list but using it gives the correct result.

Comment: I assume the "2nd time" you're referring to is the second opening of 'final_number_list.txt', not the literal second `open()` in the program...  The reason the program fails without that is that the writing done in the previous lines leaves the file positioned at the end; trying to read the file returns nothing, because there's nothing in the file after that point.  However, rewinding the file with `e.seek(0)` would be a simpler way to enable reading the file contents than reopening it.

Comment: Side note: Instead of two nested loops to find if `i` is in `list2` you can directly search the list with either `find` or `count`. Better still use a set and you can find all overlapping values with one statement: `set(list1) & set(list2)` gives you all the elements that are shared.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call `read()`, it advances the file location pointer. If you prefer, you can call `seek(0)` on the file object, which brings the file location pointer back to the beginning.